# FileHelpers -- Only read Nth Columns

Tags: c#, csv, filehelpers

I am using [FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/) to read a CSV file that have hundreds of columns but I only need the first twenty or so, so while creating the mappings in the class I only put those twenty columns.

When do the parsing, I get the following exception

> Delimiter ',' found after the last field 'CompanyDivision' (the file
>   is wrong or you need to add a field to the record class)

I read in other answers that a **hack** for this is to put dummy fields for the rest of the columns you don't want to read but, as I said, I have hundreds of those.

Is there a way to configure the engine to stop after a certain number of columns? or is there a way to extend or modify the engine to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try adding an array dummy field:

```
private string[] mDummyField;
```

With that the rest of the fields will be in that field. You must use the last version of the library.

Comment: That was the solution, thanks! Now I just need to use the Async engine because I'm getting OutOfMemory exceptions XD